# Dropdown box: How to know if a value is selected or not

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

in the code below, I need to know what choice is being selected. What is the appropriate way?  Thank you

```
$(window).ready(function() { 
    $("#Tmimata > option").each(function(index) {
         var mythis = $(this);
         if (mythis.selected) { 

         }
         else {

         }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Use `$("#Tmimata").val()`, You will get selected value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd use the [**`:selected`**](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector

```
if (mythis.is(':selected')) { 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if the element is selected, you [**should use `.prop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
if (mythis.prop('selected')) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: My workaround was if ( $('[id = "#Tmimta"] :selected').val() == mythis.val()), but yours is better